# Using serde, how can I keep a copy of the serialized data while deserializing?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm using Rust and Serde. Suppose I have a struct that wants to keep a copy of the JSON data that created it, maybe so that it can re-send that same JSON elsewhere without having to re-serialize. (And it's not as simple as just keeping a copy of the original JSON data, since the struct might be inside more JSON data.) Example:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct LargerStruct {
    value: i32,
    inner: InnerStruct,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct InnerStruct {
    this_json: String,
    inner_value: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {
          "value": 42, 
          "inner": { "inner_value": 100 }
        }
    "#;

    let val: LargerStruct = // ???

    assert_eq!(&val.inner.this_json, r#"{ "inner_value": 100 }"#);
}
```

What might fill the `???` comment?

Comment: If you want to have custom deserialization rules, you don't `#[derive(Deserialize)]`. You `impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for LargerStruct` and then you can write whatever code you want in deserialization. See https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
serde.version = "*"
serde.features = ["derive"]
serde_json.version = "*"
serde_json.features = ["raw_value"]
*/

use serde::*;
use serde_json::value::RawValue;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct LargerStruct {
    value: i32,
    inner: InnerStruct,
}

struct InnerStruct {
    this_json: String,
    inner_value: i32,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for InnerStruct {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let this_json: Box<RawValue> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct InnerStruct {
            inner_value: i32,
        }
        let this: InnerStruct =
            serde_json::from_str(this_json.get()).map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)?;

        Ok(Self{
            this_json: this_json.get().to_string(),
            inner_value: this.inner_value,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {
          "value": 42, 
          "inner": { "inner_value": 100 }
        }
    "#;

    let val: LargerStruct = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(&val.inner.this_json, r#"{ "inner_value": 100 }"#);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=719f3c93fe4624794447581c23919d41)

You can use the [`serde_json::value::RawValue`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html) type to capture the original JSON in raw form. The code uses a custom `Deserialize` implementation for `InnerStruct` to achieve the goal of capturing the JSON and deserialize. It deserializes the struct, by calling `serde_json` again on the captured JSON inside the `Deserialize` implementation. This is necessary, since the `deserializer` is consumed after deserializing the `RawValue`.

Comment: I think you can even avoid copying with `to_string()` if you tie the lifetimes of the structs to `'de`, although that might not be worth it.

Comment: The copy is necessary because `InnerStruct` is using `String` not `RawValue`. Replacing the `String` with `Box<RawValue>` allows you to directly use the `this_json` value. You could deserialize a `&'de RawValue` and use that in `InnerStruct`. That has the big downside that deserialization will sometimes fail, for example when deserializing from a `Read`, since there is nowhere to borrow from.